# Firebase 3: creating a custom authentication token using .net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Firebase 3 Authentication mechanism using Custom Tokens (as described at https:// firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens).

My server is ASP.NET MVC Application.

So according to the instructions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) I've created a service account for my Firebase application and generated a key in '.p12' format.

After that according to instructions here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) I tried to generate  a custom token and sign it using the key received on the previous step. For token generation I used SystemIdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt library from Microsoft, so the code looks like the following:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = new X509AsymmetricSecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(p12path, p12pwd));
var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-sha256");
Int32 nowInUnixTimestamp = (Int32)(now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(
            issuer: serviceAccountEmail,
            audience: "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",                
            signingCredentials: signinCredentials,
            subject: new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                    {
                    new Claim("sub", serviceAccountEmail),
                    new Claim("iat", nowInUnixTimestamp.ToString()),
                    new Claim("exp", (nowInUnixTimestamp + (60*60)).ToString()),
                    new Claim("uid", uid)
                    })
            );

var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Then tried to sign in user in React Native application using Firebase Javascript SDK, with the following code:

```
//omitting initialization code
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(firebaseJWT).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error authenticating Firebase user. Code: ' + error.code + ' Message: ' + error.message);            
        });
```

But got an error from Firebase saying:

> Error authenticating Firebase user. Code: auth/invalid-custom-token Message: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.

Experimenting with adding different claims for token expiration control didn't help either.

Also I tried to generate tokens with "dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt" library but can't get it working with "RS256" algorithm.

So the question:

**Any suggestion on what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I realized that the token format described by the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408684/is-it-still-possible-to-do-server-side-verification-of-tokens-in-firebase-3/37492640#37492640 is a token issued by Firebase itself, so the first question is not a question anymore.

Comment: Here is the answer from the Google support on the same question: **"I saw your post in SO, that you already had a workaround. For the token format, you should always follow what's on the latest documentation. There are some issues with regard to authentication right now and we're doing our best to keep things moving on our end. 
Keep an eye out on our release notes for any further updates, and feel free to check back with us if needed."**  So looks like workaround is the best option for now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This pure .NET solution works for me, using the Org.BouncyCastle (https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) and Jose.JWT (https://www.nuget.org/packages/jose-jwt/) libraries.

I followed these steps:

- In the Firebase console click the 'cog' icon which is top left, next to the project name, and click 'Permissions'.
- At the IAM and Admin page, click 'Service Accounts' on the left
- Click 'Create Service Account' at the top, enter a 'Service Account Name', select 'Project->Editor' in the Role selection, tick the 'Furnish a new private key' checkbox and select JSON
- Click 'Create' and download the Service Account JSON file and keep it safe.
- Open the Service Account JSON file in a suitable text editor and put the values into the following code:

  ```
  // private_key from the Service Account JSON file
  public static string firebasePrivateKey=@"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

  // Same for everyone
  public static string firebasePayloadAUD="https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit";

  // client_email from the Service Account JSON file
  public static string firebasePayloadISS="serviceaccountname@projectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
  public static string firebasePayloadSUB="serviceaccountname@projectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

  // the token 'exp' - max 3600 seconds - see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens
  public static int firebaseTokenExpirySecs=3600;

  private static RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters _rsaParams;
  private static object _rsaParamsLocker=new object();

  void Main() {
      // Example with custom claims
      var uid="myuserid";
      var claims=new Dictionary<string, object> {
          {"premium_account", true}
      };
      Console.WriteLine(EncodeToken(uid, claims));
  }

  public static string EncodeToken(string uid, Dictionary<string, object> claims) {
      // Get the RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters if we haven't already determined them
      if (_rsaParams == null) {
          lock (_rsaParamsLocker) {
              if (_rsaParams == null) {
                  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GenerateStreamFromString(firebasePrivateKey.Replace(@"\n","\n")));
                  var pr = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(sr);
                  _rsaParams = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();
              }
          }
      }

      var payload = new Dictionary<string, object> {
          {"claims", claims}
          ,{"uid", uid}
          ,{"iat", secondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow)}
          ,{"exp", secondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(firebaseTokenExpirySecs))}
          ,{"aud", firebasePayloadAUD}
          ,{"iss", firebasePayloadISS}
          ,{"sub", firebasePayloadSUB}
      };

      return Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(_rsaParams), JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
  }

  private static long secondsSinceEpoch(DateTime dt) {
      TimeSpan t = dt - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
      return (long)t.TotalSeconds;
  }

  private static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s) {
      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
      writer.Write(s);
      writer.Flush();
      stream.Position = 0;
      return stream;
  }
  ```

To get this working in IIS I needed to change the application's pool identity and set the "load user profile" setting to true.

Comment: Hi I have tried your code. When I check generated token in https://jwt.io/ it is saying invalid signature.

Comment: @AjayPunekar the code is still working for me. Did you work this out?

Comment: @Elliveny I tried the code, token is generated but I get "The custom token format is incorrect" error message when I send it to firebase, any idea?

Comment: @RezaRahmati I can't help without seeing your code. Maybe raise a new question with the details?

Comment: @Elliveny I copy paste your code it's exactly the same only variable values are different

Comment: @RezaRahmati what line of the code is giving you the 'the custom token format is incorrect' error message?

Comment: @Elliveny Sorry I confused you, this works fine and will generate token successfully, when I pass token to firebase via `SignInWithCustomToken` I get error from firebase, means that there is an issue with the token

Comment: @Elliveny I found what was wrong with my code, I was passing linkedin token to signInWithCustomToken by mistake

Answer (score 2):

Haven't found a direct answer for the question so far, so for now ended up with the following solution:

[Using instruction here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) generated a JSON file with service account details and created a basic Node.js server using Firebase server SDK that does generate correct custom tokens for Firebase with the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var httpdispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
    serviceAccount: {
    projectId: "{projectId}",
    clientEmail: "{projectServiceEmail}",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ... ---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  },
  databaseURL: "https://{projectId}.firebaseio.com"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);    

const PORT=8080; 

httpdispatcher.onGet("/firebaseCustomToken", function(req, res) {
    var uid = req.params.uid;

    if (uid) {
        var customToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({'firebaseJWT' : customToken}));
    } else {
        res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('No uid parameter specified');
    }
});    

function handleRequest(request, response){
     try {
        //log the request on console
        console.log(request.url);
        //Disptach
        httpdispatcher.dispatch(request, response);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }    
}

//create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){       
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Maybe someone will find this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

@Elliveny's answer worked great for me. I am using it in a .NET Core 2.0 application and have built upon the accepted answer to turn this solution into a class that can be registered as a singleton dependency in the app services container, as well as have configuration passed in via constructor so that we can leverage .NET secrets for local development configuration and environment variables for production configuration.

I have also tidied up the stream handling a bit.

**Note for .NET Core devs** - you'll need to use [Portable.BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.BouncyCastle/)

You can test your encoded results by parsing the output JWT token with [Jwt.IO](https://jwt.io/)

```
using Jose;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class FirebaseTokenGenerator
{
    // private_key from the Service Account JSON file
    public static string firebasePrivateKey;

    // Same for everyone
    public static string firebasePayloadAUD = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit";

    // client_email from the Service Account JSON file
    public static string firebasePayloadISS;
    public static string firebasePayloadSUB;

    // the token 'exp' - max 3600 seconds - see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens
    public static int firebaseTokenExpirySecs = 3600;

    private static RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters _rsaParams;
    private static object _rsaParamsLocker = new object();

    public FirebaseTokenGenerator(string privateKey, string clientEmail)
    {
        firebasePrivateKey = privateKey ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(privateKey));
        firebasePayloadISS = clientEmail ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientEmail));
        firebasePayloadSUB = clientEmail;
    }

    public static string EncodeToken(string uid)
    {
        return EncodeToken(uid, null);
    }

    public static string EncodeToken(string uid, Dictionary<string, object> claims)
    {
        // Get the RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters if we haven't already determined them
        if (_rsaParams == null)
        {
            lock (_rsaParamsLocker)
            {
                if (_rsaParams == null)
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = WriteToStreamWithString(firebasePrivateKey.Replace(@"\n", "\n")))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(streamWriter.BaseStream))
                        {
                            var pr = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(sr);
                            _rsaParams = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        {"uid", uid}
        ,{"iat", SecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow)}
        ,{"exp", SecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(firebaseTokenExpirySecs))}
        ,{"aud", firebasePayloadAUD}
        ,{"iss", firebasePayloadISS}
        ,{"sub", firebasePayloadSUB}
    };

        if (claims != null && claims.Any())
        {
            payload.Add("claims", claims);
        }

        return JWT.Encode(payload, Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(_rsaParams), JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
    }


    private static long SecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime dt)
    {
        TimeSpan t = dt - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        return (long) t.TotalSeconds;
    }

    private static StreamWriter WriteToStreamWithString(string s)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return writer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The @Elliveny's code worked for me in locally but in azure throws an error : "The system cannot find the file specified". Due that I have changed a little bit the code and now works in both servers.

```
private string EncodeToken(string uid, Dictionary<string, object> claims)
    {

        string jwt = string.Empty;
        RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters _rsaParams;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GenerateStreamFromString(private_key.Replace(@"\n", "\n"))))
        {
            var pr = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(sr);
            _rsaParams = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pr.ReadObject();
        }


        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> payload = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                {"claims", claims}
                ,{"uid", uid}
                ,{"iat", secondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow)}
                ,{"exp", secondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(firebaseTokenExpirySecs))}
                ,{"aud", firebasePayloadAUD}
                ,{"iss", client_email}
                ,{"sub", client_email}
            };

            RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(_rsaParams);
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            jwt = JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
        }

        return jwt;

    }
```